# When splicing a Python list how would I specify that I want it to create including all the elements following the first one specified?

Tags: python, list

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(numbers[1:]) 
print(numbers[1:0])
```

I want to get the same result as the first print statement but with a number after the colon. My question is what number would I put after that colon to get the same result(new list with numbers from index 1 to end of list)?

Comment: Have you tried ```print(numbers[1:5])```?

Comment: You can put any number that is equal to or greater than `len(numbers)` or you can use `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to do something like

```
print(numbers[1:len(numbers)])
```

Anything else leads to a shorter list than you want.

```
numbers[1:0]  # empty list
numbers[1:-1]  # loses the last value
```

of course, `numbers[1:]` is actually the best way to go about it, so I'm curious why you explicitly need the number included.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I was just curious about why numbers[1:0] and
numbers[1:-1]  don't work and wanted to understand the logic behind it.